# How to fetch a word from a database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the PHP code for fetching a word that was entered by the user. May I ask on how to show the result of "jhon dewey" if the user entered the keyword "john" on my website as "jhon" only without the last name?

My database fields are:

`first_name` (contains the first name records)

`last_name` (contains the last name records)

This is my code. Please help me find the error. Can I change the %john% into a variable so that any word entered by the user can search to my database?

```
<?php

// Database connection

$sql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "MYPassword", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno ()) {
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM `usage` WHERE 'first_name' LIKE %john%";
$result = $sql->query($query);
if (!$result)
    die($mysqli->error);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
$sql->close();

print("<pre>");
print_r($rows);
print("</pre>");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Patterns are string literals so they must be wrapped with single quotes.
- Second, column names are identifiers so they shouldn't be wrap with single quotes as single quotes are for string literals.

Snippet:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `usage` WHERE `first_name` LIKE '%john%'"
```

Since your column name is not a reserved keyword, backticks are optional on this case

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `usage` WHERE first_name LIKE '%john%'"
```

Comment: Thank you but there is an error:

    Notice:  Undefined variable: rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\capturer.php on line 25

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm almost getting it. But here is the result:

    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => john
            [last_name] => dewey
        )

    )


How could i remove the "array" and other characters the except for the [first_name]=>john and [last_name]=>dewey

i want that if the user enters a keyword and it is not found in my database, it would show an error, else if a matching word is found, it would show the two records that contains the matching word on the    
FIRST field only. Thank you so much.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you here but it sounds like you want to output the results different to how print_r does? print_r dumps variables in a "human readable" form and is probably not great for end user results. Rather use something like echo and referencing the elements in $rows that way you can control how the output looks?

Comment: Also if you're only looking for the first match, consider changing your query to something like "SELECT ... LIMIT 1" to only return a maximum of one row. Also consider eliminating the while loop, seems redundant if you're only looking for one result.

Comment: Thank you but I am not good in programming and this is my first time in PhP. Would you mind if i will ask for the "echo' tag in order to select for the first field only? i am going to link this code to my form in my website. thank you so much and apologize for asking so much help. I've been doing it for many days already and been searching for it night and day.

Comment: have you look at this link? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Not yet. I have to look at this. Thanks.

Comment: To JW:
I checked the link, I modified it to like this but the result screen is empty.

Comment: <?php

// from the user form
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];


// Database connection

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "143j3sus", "words");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM mylist WHERE keyword like '%$keyword%'";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["keyword"], $row["definition"]);
    }

Comment: /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
<?php

// Database connection

$sql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "MYPassword", "test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno ()) {
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM `usage` WHERE `first_name` LIKE '%john%'";
$result = $sql->query($query);
if (!$result)
    die($mysqli->error);
$rows = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$result->close();
$sql->close();

print("<pre>");
print_r($rows);
print("</pre>");
?>
```